# Solace NIFI JMSConnectionFactoryProvider unbinding/binding

Tags: apache-nifi, solace

Using the JNDI Connection Factory Provider for Apache NiFi from http://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/nifi/

The site I'm trying consume messages from (running Solace JMS) is seeing the client (NiFi ConsumeJMS processor) continually unbinding/binding to the queue with a reason of "Client issued unbind". And the client is unable to consume all of the data and it is resulting in "Messages expired to discard". What's causing the unbinding/binding and what can I do to solve this using the this Nifi processor.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache NiFi is closing the `MessageConsumer` after the consumption of every message.

You can refer to the source of `org.apache.nifi.jms.processors.JMSConsumer` [here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jms-bundle/nifi-jms-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/jms/processors/JMSConsumer.java).

```
public void consume(final String destinationName, final ConsumerCallback consumerCallback) {
    this.jmsTemplate.execute(new SessionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInJms(Session session) throws JMSException {
                ...
                JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(msgConsumer);
```

The default behavior of the Solace JMS API is to deliver a batch of messages to the consumer. However, because NiFi is repeatedly closing the connection after only consuming 1 message, this results in the remainder of the batch to be re-delivered to the next Consumer that is created.

I believe that you must have enabled the "Max Redelivery" setting on the endpoint, and the maximum amount of redeliveries of those messages that were "expired to discard" were exceeded.

The solution here is to adjust the "Max Delivered Unacked Messages Per Flow" setting on the endpoint to 1 to ensure that only 1 message can be in flight.

It is also a good idea to adjust the "AD Window Size" message reception property in the connection factory to 1, to ensure optimal performance.